# In Cloud Datastore how do I figure out what quota I am breaking if all dashboards show 'Okay"

Tags: java, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Thank you for getting this far, let's see if we can solve this.

We have a Spring Boot app that we are using to upload a small amount of data into Google Cloud Datastore. Today for no reason that we can detect we are unable to add or remove data because of an error similar to:

```
2015-03-25 17:22:41 INFO  c.i.m.c.p.PersistenceHelperBase:189 - Committing transaction to datastore
2015-03-25 17:22:41 ERROR c.i.m.c.p.PersistenceHelperBase:206 - Error commit entity to Google Data Store: {} com.google.api.services.datastore.client.DatastoreException: The API call datastore_v4.Commit() required more quota than is available. at com.google.api.services.datastore.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:115) ~[google-api-services-datastore-protobuf-v1beta2-rev1-2.1.2.jar!/:na]
```

Upon Googling this issue we immediately checked under the Developer Console -> Compute -> App Engine -> Quota details only to find out that everything is reporting 'Okay'. A brief flash of insight had us check Developer Console -> APIs & auth -> APIs -> Cloud Datastore APIs -> Quotas which shows we are far under the posted quota there.

The data that we are working with is small, only a few K per entity. So we should be avoiding those quotas.

We are stuck on figuring out where we are hitting the quotas. Where else should we be looking?

**UPDATE**:
I'm going to mark the below as the answer but for us it ended up being not completely correct. We were given a link into the old App Engine interface that clearly showed that we were over quota while the Developers Console did not show that information.

If you are having this problem please try to hit `https://appengine.google.com/dashboard` and hopefully you won't have the same issues that we did with `https://console.developers.google.com` falling short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Cloud Datastore, projects that do not have billing enabled only get limited writes before reaching the quota.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Datastore

**To view your current quota consumption:**

1. Go to https://appengine.google.com/dashboard
2. Click your Project's Name
3. Look at the different quotas

If you are doing a lot of writes, you are going to run into this quota very quickly!

To fix this, you have to enable billing. This will remove the write quota.

**How to enable billing:**

1. Sign in to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com).
2. Create a new account or sign in to an existing account
3. Create a new project or select an existing project
4. On the project's page, select **Settings**
5. List item Click **Enable Billing**.
6. You are now in the page that controls the billing account for your project. Fill in the form that specifies the billing that will apply to this project only.
7. Click **Submit and enable billing**

Also note, you can cap your budget down to $0 so you only spend what you mean to.

Comment: Billing is enabled for the project and we have made sure that the app-engine budget is set to 0 but we are still having the same problems.